# When you create a custom post type, does that also create capabilities for editing/deleting that post type automatically?

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

For example, if I create a post type called "destinations" does that automatically create capabilities like "edit_destinations" or "delete_destinations"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not automatically create that capability in the sense that there is no new capability registered with WordPress. Instead it defaults to use the capabilities assigned to creating/editing posts. For example, if an author logs in they will be able to create and publish a new destination entry by default.

You can override this with the `capabilities` value when using `register_post_type`. See Justin Tadlock's excellent tutorial here http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress

Comment: hehe, coincidentally i was just reading Justin Tadlock's articles! Good stuff! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Define a central variable for the custom post type: `public $post_type_1 = 'archiv';`

and use this on add new capabilities:

```
        $capabilities = array(
            'edit_post'          => 'edit_' . $this->post_type_1,
            'edit_posts'         => 'edit_' . $this->post_type_1 . 's',
            'edit_others_posts'  => 'edit_others_' . $this->post_type_1 . 's',
            'publish_posts'      => 'publish_' . $this->post_type_1 . 's',
            'read_post'          => 'read_' . $this->post_type_1,
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_' . $this->post_type_1 . 's',
            'delete_post'        => 'delete_' . $this->post_type_1
        );
```

Also i add this new capabilties objects to the differnet default roles, only on activation of the plugin:

```
        foreach ( $this->todo_roles as $role ) {
            $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'edit_'          . $this->post_type_1 );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'edit_'          . $this->post_type_1 . 's' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'edit_others_'   . $this->post_type_1 . 's' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'publish_'       . $this->post_type_1 . 's' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'read_'          . $this->post_type_1 );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'read_private_'  . $this->post_type_1 . 's' );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'delete_'        . $this->post_type_1 );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'manage_'        . $this->taxonomy_type_1 );
        }

        foreach ( $this->read_roles as $role ) {
            $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'read_' . $this->post_type_1 );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'read_' . $this->post_type_1 );
            $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'read_' . $this->post_type_1 );
        }

        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

But, you must also unregister this objects, when the plugin will be uninstalled.

You can see an example on this gist: https://gist.github.com/978690

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Hey, quick question: when you use the add_cap function, is that the same function that plugins like "Capability Manager" or "Members" plugins use in their inner workings?

Comment: yep, the plugins use also this function.

Comment: @bueltge why do you need to `flush_rules()` after adding capabilities? Also, if you use the following code to register capabilities for a custom post type: `'capability_type' => array('archives', 'archive'), 'map_meta_cap' => true,` then when adding a capability, for example `edit_archive` capability using `add_cap` method, doesn't it get expanded to include corresponding primitive caps: `edit_archives, edit_published_archives, edit_other_archives and edit_private_archives`. OR do they have to be added separately?

Comment: @bueltge I got very confused with capabilities and trying to understand them better, if my comment doesn't make much sense, please have a look at my full question here http://tiny.cc/ybbo4 Many thanks :)

Comment: @bueltge Also, after adding the capabilities to the admin role (the same set of capabilities as you have in `todo_roles` loop) the admin user still can't even edit others custom posts, and I don't understand why :S