# Explanation of User Roles and Capabilities

Tags: theme-development, user-roles, capabilities

I'm developing a Wordpress theme. In this theme, there are a few custom post types.

Custom Post Types :

- book
- article
- event

We are using Wordpress' default user roles (we can create new roles, if necessary) .

Contributors just post new **book** and **article** . But they can't create **event**. Also they can't see, *event* menu item on **wp-admin** .

How can i do this ?

While registering new post type :

```
"map_meta_cap" => TRUE,
"capability_type" => "book",
```

And (on plugin activation)

```
$role = get_role( 'contributor' ); 

$role->add_cap( 'publish_books' );
```

But I think it's still not working. it's so complicated for me. I couldn't do it. I just want this roles and capabilities :

### Administrator

Can see , post , publish everything

### Contributors

Just can  see, post to review **book** and **article**
Can NOT see other post types on wp-admin menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can create capabilities for each custom post type and add this to the different roles; see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21367/when-you-create-a-custom-post-type-does-that-also-create-capabilities-for-editi/21504#21504) from an question here.